# How to mark Spring MVC params as required

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have such method in spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateArticle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void updateArticle(Long id,  String name, String description) {
  ...
}
```

I want the id, and name to be REQUIRED. In the other words, if they are null values, then an exception must be thrown.

How can I do that? Is there any annotation for this or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. `@RequestParam(required=true)` See the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

Required flag is even true by default, so all you need to do is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateArticle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void updateArticle(@RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String description) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: can I validate not to be null too? or not to be whitespace?

Comment: There is no way you can pass _null_ as request parameter. Giving, let's say,`?name=` will result with empty string assigned to name. For a more sophisticated validation you'll need to use response from @blackpanther plus maybe implement a custom javax.validation.ConstraintValidator (some spring docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/previews/validation.html) )

Comment: thank you again. Spring have org.springframework.validation.Validator
for this. that is nice, but I must create new class with parameters, I do not like that style of coding. that's all. I do not want to create new class for parameters...

Comment: note, that it is more standard way to do post requests - mapping a form to a POJO. You gain much more power when using this approach and the code is way more readable in case your updated entity has bigger number of properties. You can also switch url encoded form to a JSON or XML without touching your implementation - just reconfiguring MVC.

Comment: If we have many parameters, POST and GET will be better in POJO. I Agree. But when I have one or two parameter, it will be nice, if we have more flexible validate functionality in spring when we write params in method too. If we write in POJO spring have very very good validations.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add RequestParam with required true annotation in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateArticle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void updateArticle(@RequestParam(value="id",required=true) long id,@RequestParam(value="name",required=true)  String name, @RequestParam(value="description",required=true) String description) {
  ...
}
```

When you will hit this controller URL from browser and if one of the param is mission then you will get `incorrect syntax error` on browser

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are passing a form to this controller. Therefore, convert all the form fields into a Form object and then you can use Java validations on them. So, for example, you have the id, name and description fields in the form:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class ArticleForm {

    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
    private String name;

    @Size(min =2, max =20)
    private String description;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then, in your controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/updateArticle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public void updateArticle(@Valid ArticleForm articleForm) {
      // do something with the article form object using getters and this retrieves
      // values sent in the HTTP Form
 }
```

Comment: Although correct approach is not what the OP wants. It does not throw exception, rather collects constraint violation information

Comment: @grid actually no, if a user does not put a name in the form, an exception will be thrown. And besides, if this is the correct approach, then shouldn't this be the pattern - it's part of good practice and design.

Comment: it depends on how you use the JSR 303 api, or how it integrates with your framework. When integrated with spring-mvc you have no exception bubbling up afaik. It does when used with Jpa. The question asks for request parameter validation, although the use case seems to be resolved more properly by your answer and forget about the exception

Comment: what about this? for instance GET with this url "?name="

Comment: I mean, when we have parameters in method, not in POJO.

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/gethomeworkinfo.json", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody
HomeworkReport getHomeworkReportInfo(@RequestParam (value = "schoolid", required = false) String schoolId, @RequestParam (value = "homeworkid") String homeworkId,
        @RequestParam (value = "startdate", required = false, defaultValue = "2014-06-01") @DateTimeFormat (pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date startdate,
        @RequestParam (value = "enddate", required = false, defaultValue = "2014-12-30") @DateTimeFormat (pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date enddate,
        @RequestParam (value = "userid", required = false) String userId, HttpServletRequest request) {

    // some actions
```

}

I currently use this method. It will help you.